# Nested Histogram Query in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the below set of documnets
Is there any way we can make a nested histogram search in elastic search

```
{"id": 1, "regions" : 111, "category" : 6, "Price" : 957}
{"id": 2, "regions" : 111, "category" : 6, "Price" : 829}
{"id": 3, "regions" : 111, "category" : 7, "Price" : 123}
{"id": 4, "regions" : 111, "category" : 7, "Price" : 129}
{"id": 5, "regions" : 111, "category" : 8, "Price" : 351}
{"id": 6, "regions" : 111, "category" : 8, "Price" : 225}

{"id": 7, "regions" : 112, "category" : 6, "Price" : 625}
{"id": 8, "regions" : 112, "category" : 6, "Price" : 599}
{"id": 9, "regions" : 112, "category" : 7, "Price" : 256}
{"id": 10, "regions" : 112, "category" : 7, "Price" : 129}
{"id": 11, "regions" : 112, "category" : 8, "Price" : 333}
{"id": 12, "regions" : 112, "category" : 8, "Price" : 444}
{"id": 13, "regions" : 112, "category" : 9, "Price" : 199}
{"id": 14, "regions" : 112, "category" : 9, "Price" : 149}
{"id": 15, "regions" : 112, "category" : 5, "Price" : 299}
{"id": 16, "regions" : 112, "category" : 5, "Price" : 349}
```

I need to make a query(may be some nested histogram or other ) to get the output in the below format
Every region should have distinct category with least price.

```
[{
        "regions" : 111,
        [{
                "category" : 6,
                "Price" : 829
            }, {
                "category" : 7,
                "Price" : 123
            }, {
                "category" : 8,
                "Price" : 225
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "regions" : 112,
        [{
                "category" : 6,
                "Price" : 599
            }, {
                "category" : 7,
                "Price" : 129
            }, {
                "category" : 8,
                "Price" : 333
            }, {
                "category" : 9,
                "Price" : 149
            }, {
                "category" : 5,
                "Price" : 299
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.  ElasticSearch is not going to spit out the data in exactly the format that you specified.  You'll need to use a query to filter down the results you're looking for and then loop through each result putting the data you want into the structure you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can index the data using the `_bulk` API. Something like this:

```
$ curl -XPOST localhost:9200/my_index/data/_bulk -d '{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"regions" : 111, "category" : 6, "Price" : 957}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"regions" : 111, "category" : 6, "Price" : 829}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"regions" : 111, "category" : 7, "Price" : 123}
{"index":{"_id":"4"}}
{"regions" : 111, "category" : 7, "Price" : 129}
{"index":{"_id":"5"}}
{"regions" : 111, "category" : 8, "Price" : 351}
{"index":{"_id":"6"}}
{"regions" : 111, "category" : 8, "Price" : 225}
'
```

Blank lines are important with the `_bulk` endpoint, so the way I have used it was quite intentional.

Then you would have an index that is mapped with the `regions`, `category`, and `Price` indexed as `long` values. From there, you could use an aggregation to get the histogram you're asking for:

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_search -d '{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_region": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "regions",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_category": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category",
            "size": 10
          },
          "min_price": {
            "min": {
              "field": "Price"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This won't give the output as you literally put it, but it will give you the values that you're looking for. Note: I picked arbitrary sizes. Also, the names like "group_by_region" are up to you; they're something that you will see in the response and the name is completely arbitrary.